# Flexible Box Layout in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera, flexbox

There is a strange behavior with flex boxes in Opera (26). Setting height flex-div's descendant in relative units (%) leads to calculation absolute height not from its ancestor, but from the top div in my case. There is no problem with width or absolute units. In Firefox it's ok.
Is it a bug of Opera or I understand spec wrong?

Source:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-cont {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;  
}
.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='flex-cont' style='position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px'>
        <div class='flex-item'>
            <div style='width:100%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='flex-item'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a known bug in Blink (used by Chrome and Opera) regarding flex items that are "stretch-aligned" (like in your test).

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341310

Your test is valid, and the spec is very clear on this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#algo-stretch

You should however consider inserting a <!DOCTYPE html> line at the top, so that browsers don't enter quirks mode. Blink fails differently with your test, depending on quirks mode or not. :)

Comment: Thanks, I supposed that, but there were doubts.